# Strange click event pattern with input search box and unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

I am experiencing a strange pattern in my current project. I have tried searching SO and Google, however I am unsure of what exactly exactly to search. To sum up my problem:

I have set up a replication JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r3gp3quv/). I have experienced the following behavior in (Windows) Chrome, Waterfox, and Edge. Basically, I have a text input serving as a search field. When the value of the input changes, a database is searched and valid responses are added as list elements to an unordered list. In the fiddle, the database backend is replaced with an array.

When input changes, the entire list is cleared and then refilled based upon the search query. The problem arises when I use the list as a "menu" - I am listening for the `click` event on each li. When I type something in the box then click on a list item, the click event is not triggered. When I click on a list item again, the click *is* triggered, and every click after that works (until I enter another query). Here's the weird part: after the click events for a certain search query are triggered, if I clear the input and type the same query again, the list items are clickable instantly, even though they have just been cleared and reinstated.

To replicate this behavior:

1. Enter "ma" into the input
2. Click one of the results once (nothing is printed to the console)
3. Click one of the results again (`Clicked!` is printed to the console)
4. Clear the input and type something else, but don't click any results
5. Clear the input and type "ma" again
6. Click one of the results. It should be instantly clickable
7. Entering a different query will make the results not immediately "clickable"

I am making case-insensitive comparisons with the search query, yet typing "Ma" (or "MA" or "mA") in step 5 will not make the results instantly clickable.

I have seen this behavior in three different browsers. I would not be so confused if the behavior was consistent. So my question is two-fold:

1. Why does the click event not get triggered the first time (for a "new" query)? I'm guessing it has to do with the input losing focus.
2. Why does the click event get triggered instantly when the query that last became clickable is entered, even after the unordered list is cleared several times and repopulated?

Also, is there something other than unordered lists that I should be using to provide a list of clickable search results?

Thanks in advance!

As requested by Stack Overflow's post editor, here is the code of the replication:

HTML:

```html
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="text-input" />
    </form>
    <ul id="results-list">
    </ul>
</body>
```

JS:

```js
var entries = ["Jason Stewart", "George Bacon", "Martha Stewart", "Cliff Mandarin", "Luke Barnes", "Spandex Assassin"];

$(function() {
    $("#text-input").on("keyup change", function() {
        $("#results-list").html("");
        if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
          return;
        }
        var query = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = entries[i];
            if (entry.toUpperCase().indexOf(query) >= 0) {
                $("#results-list").html($("#results-list").html() + "<li>" + entry + "</li>");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#results-list").on("click", "li", function(evt) {
        console.log("Clicked!");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the click event not get triggered the first time (for a "new" query)? I'm guessing it has to do with the input losing focus.

Because you're destroying the list elements and recreating them on the `change` event, which happens when focus leaves the text box if the value has changed since focus entered the text box, even if nothing has changed since the last `keyup` did its work. The element you clicked is no longer present; an identical replacement is there instead.

> Why does the click event get triggered instantly when the query that last became clickable is entered, even after the unordered list is cleared several times and repopulated?

Because `change` doesn't fire in that case; the value hasn't changed.

You can fix it by simply remembering the last value you processed and not replacing the list unless it's changed. That way, the `keyup` updates the list and the `change` doesn't: [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r3gp3quv/1/)

```
var entries = ["Jason Stewart", "George Bacon", "Martha Stewart", "Cliff Mandarin", "Luke Barnes", "Spandex Assassin"];

$(function() {
    var lastValue = undefined;                         // **
    $("#text-input").on("keyup change", function() {
        var thisValue = $(this).val();                 // **
        if (lastValue == thisValue) {                  // **
            return;                                    // **
        }                                              // **
        lastValue = thisValue;                         // **
        $("#results-list").html("");
        if (thisValue.length <= 0) {                   // **
          return;
        }
        var query = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = entries[i];
            if (entry.toUpperCase().indexOf(query) >= 0) {
                $("#results-list").html($("#results-list").html() + "<li>" + entry + "</li>");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#results-list").on("click", "li", function(evt) {
        console.log("Clicked!");
    });

});
```

---

You might also want to add the `input` and `paste` events to your event list.

---

If you want to get a better understanding of why it's happening, adding the event name to the elements when you fill them in can help: Just update your original fiddle (not my fix above) to accept the `e` argument to your handler function and change the line adding the list item to include `e.type` in the text: [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/r3gp3quv/2/)

```
$("#results-list").html($("#results-list").html() + "<li>" + entry + " [" + e.type + "]</li>");
```

If you type `ma`, you'll see `keyup`, but when you try to click, you'll see the entries replaced with `change` ones instead.